# I want to plot multiple values in a same ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

i'm trying to plot multiple variables in the same ggplot and i want to change the color of the line based on the year. This is what i have so far but i want it to be easier to understand so im trying to do it:

```
ggplot(data = larceny_cases_districts, aes(x = Year, y = Cases))+
    geom_line(color = "#d62f53", size = 2 )+
    geom_point(shape = 21, color = "black", fill = "black", size = 6)+
    geom_text(aes(label = Cases), hjust=-1,vjust=0.1, color="#ff0000")+
    theme_ipsum()+
    ggtitle("Larceny Crimes in 2015-2018")
```

This is how my dataframe is set right now:

```
  larceny_cases_districts
  Year Cases
1 2015  2895
2 2016  4561
3 2017  4450
4 2018  2982
```

But i want it to look a bit like this so i can use `colour = var_value` to make multiple lines on `geom_line()` but i cant find a way to make this viable:

```
 larceny_cases_districts
              District 2015  2016  2017  2018
            1 A1      value value value value
            2 D4    value value value value
            3 B2    value value value value
```

My goal is to make a plot that has 3 lines and each one is the value of each year for each district

output of `dput(head(larceny_cases_districts, 20))`:

```
structure(list(District = c("A1", "D4", "B2"), `2015` = c(10L, 
    6L, 1L), `2016` = c(13L, 8L, 8L), `2017` = c(10L, 2L, 6L), `2018` = c(13L, 
    2L, 3L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problems generaly has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

If the original data already is in long format, there is *no need* for the `dplyr/tidyr` pipe prior to the plotting instructions below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

larceny_cases_districts %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('20'),
    names_to = 'Year',
    values_to = 'Cases'
  ) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.integer(Year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, Cases, fill = District)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, color = "black", size = 6) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Cases), hjust = -1, vjust = 0.1, color = "#ff0000") +
  ggtitle("Larceny Crimes in 2015-2018") +
  theme_ipsum()
```

[image]

**Data**

```
larceny_cases_districts <- 
structure(list(District = c("A1", "D4", "B2"), `2015` = c(10L, 
    6L, 1L), `2016` = c(13L, 8L, 8L), `2017` = c(10L, 2L, 6L), 
    `2018` = c(13L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: To make this plot you changed the values in here?

`larceny_cases_districts <- read.table(text = "
District 2015  2016  2017  2018
1 A1      value value value value
2 D4    value value value value
3 B2    value value value value
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: @GuilhermeFrediani Yes, I have. That's what the `lapply` after `read.table` is doing. The values sampled are completely different from yours but the general principle of plotting the graph is the same.

Comment: can you explain to me more about each line of your solution, please?

Comment: @GuilhermeFrediani If the data is in long format, there is a x axis variable and a y axis one. Then, in order to separate the lines, a grouping variable. In this case it's `fill = District`. Had it been `color = District` in the initial call to `ggplot` and the lines would have been colored by groups of `District`. And `ggplot` separates the groups automatically.

Comment: Ok, but like, i'll try to change the values of the plot, what do i need to do for that?

Comment: i would like to use real values that i have from the data frame to create the plot

Comment: @GuilhermeFrediani Can you post the output of `dput(head(larceny_cases_districts, 20))` in the question? Like this it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Ill post it in the question

Comment: @GuilhermeFrediani Done, see now.

Comment: so i just need to change the values inside the () now?

Comment: Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
#Code
ggplot(data = larceny_cases_districts, aes(x = Year,
                                           y = Cases,
                                           color=factor(Year),
                                           group=1,
                                           fill=factor(Year)))+
  geom_line(size = 2 )+
  geom_point(shape = 21, color = "black", size = 6)+
  geom_text(aes(label = Cases), hjust=-1,vjust=0.1, color="#ff0000")+
  theme_ipsum()+
  ggtitle("Larceny Crimes in 2015-2018")
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
larceny_cases_districts <- structure(list(Year = 2015:2018, Cases = c(2895L, 4561L, 4450L, 
2982L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"
))
```

Comment: This is closer to what i was expecting but i want something to be more like this:

A single plot like you did but with 3 different lines and each point represents the larceny cases of a district, for example, the red line would be 2015 and the first point would be A1, then D4 and finally B2. And the color of the line is determined by each year

Comment: @GuilhermeFrediani Like a bar plot but using lines?

Comment: idk what that would look like actually hahahahahahahahaha

Comment: can you explain to me what the "L" after que values mean?

Comment: It is one `1` and it creates a line grouped only by itself!

Comment: Ok! Thank You so much!